# Как склеить 2 немного отличающиеся части одного изображения из canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, обработка-изображений

Есть 2 скриншота примерно такого вида:

[image: первый]
[image: второй]

На каждом из них есть часть другого, попиксельно общие части не идентичны (jpeg-артефакты, подсветка и другие мелкие отличия). Как собрать их в один длинный, если известно что общая часть у первого снизу, а у второго сверху? Итоговая картинка должна быть примерно такой:

[image: итоговый]

Предполагаю что нечто подобное используется при создании панорам, например, следовательно должны существовать готовые решения.

Comment: простой (и медленный) способ может заключаться в перебирании всех смещений `y`, подсчёта некоторого значения похожести (например, число совпадающих пикселей, или сумма квадратов разностей компонент `r`, `g` и `b` для каждого пикселя) и выбирания смещения с наилучшим значением похожести

Comment: способ, предложенный в предыдущем комментарии, можно ускорить, сделав это в несколько этапов, начав с данных изображений с разрешением, уменьшенным в десятки раз, и на каждом этапе увеличивать разрешение и уменьшать дельту сдвига